# Nofollow on share links?

Tags: links, nofollow, social-media, social-sharing-buttons

I looked up on Google about this and most of the articles talk about not making `nofollow` links my social pages, instead making them `rel="me"`, I got that. But I want to know if it is a good idea to add `nofollow` to share links such as:

- `<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=..." rel="nofollow">Share</a>`
- `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=..." rel="nofollow">Share</a>`
- `<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=..." rel="nofollow">Share</a>`
- and so on

What's your take on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nofollow` needs to be used only:

- when you don't trust the links (in your case links to Twitter, Facebook, Google+, etc.)
- for paid links
- for crawl prioritization

You are not in these 3 cases, that's why if I were you I wouldn't add `nofollow` to these links.

More info about `nofollow` on [this Google's support page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en).